# Skype for Business Web App - Linux Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, skype

i have small application which is written in javascript by using skype web sdk.
i can add user to my list and call the person and have conversation easily and the code works well.

the problem is chrome on windows; rings the person around **10seconds** but chrome on linux rings the same person around **60 seconds**.

what i tried?

- i upgraded or downgraded the chrome versions. but the result is same.
- i tried on ubuntu or fedora or slax.
- i tried with different remote skype id.

any help will be graceful appreciated.

thanks